# Does a git commit contain metadata that identifies the user's device

Tags: git

If I commit and push code from several devices to a single repo in Github, is it possible to determine which commit came from which device?
Devices can be on the same or different networks.

Does a `git commit` metadata contain any unique identifier for the device, external identifiers such as ip address, or internally generated identifiers such as uuid?

I am asking this question out of curiosity, I don't intend to add such information to my commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git cat-file -p $thatcommitid` prints the entirety of the commit metadata, that's literally all there is in it, zlib compressed with a type and length header showing that it's a commit and how long what you see printed is.  So, no.

Answer (score 3):

> contain any unique identifier for the device, external identifiers such as ip address, or internally generated identifiers such as uuid

No, but if you are looking to add this kind of information to your commits, you can either:

- use [git notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes)
- use a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_applypatch_msg) to automatically change the commit message to include the information you are after